# Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceCollection<T> exception: Entity set name has not been provided for an entity of type

Tags: c#, entity-framework, odata

I am getting following exception while using an instance of Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceCollection and calling either Load(...) or Add(...) on it: 
Entity set name has not been provided for an entity of type .

For example:

```
DataServiceCollection<TEntity> collection = 
new DataServiceCollection<TEntity>(_repoDataServiceQuery);
collection.Load(entity);
```

Any suggestions on what am I missing to avoid the exception?

Answer (score 5):

Is _repoDataServicerQuery a query of entityset or an IEnumerable of entities you got from server? In that case, you don't need to provide the entityset name when constructing DataServiceCollection, it will find and set it for you since there's enough information contained in the query or the items. Otherwise, if you just want an empty DataServiceCollection to add or load entities in, you need to set the entityset name to tell it which entityset you want to add to or load from. For instance:

```
DataServiceCollection<Customer> customers =
    new DataServiceCollection<Customer>(context, "Customers"/*entityset name*/, null, null);
var customer = new Customer();
customers.Add(customer);
```

The constructor is

```
public DataServiceCollection(DataServiceContext context, string entitySetName, Func<EntityChangedParams, bool> entityChangedCallback, Func<EntityCollectionChangedParams, bool> collectionChangedCallback);
```

The last two Func can simply be `null`.

Comment: Julin, thanks for the quick reply. Yes, here is how _repoDataServiceQuery is declared: protected readonly DataServiceQuery<TEntity> _repoDataServiceQuery;

Comment: And how about its value? Was it assigned with something like `context.TEntities`(entityset of TEntity)?